# Problem to upload images with variables with Twurl - BASH SCRIPT

Tags: bash, image, variables

`twurl -H upload.twitter.com "/1.1/media/upload.json" -f ${image} -F media -X POST`

This return `ERROR: File not found`

But if i do a `echo "twurl -H upload.twitter.com "/1.1/media/upload.json" -f ${image} -F media -X POST"` 
And then copy the result in the terminal there is no problem

Result of the echo:

`{"media_id":1205943402870779904,"media_id_string":"1205943402870779904","size":56477,"expires_after_secs":86400,"image":{"image_type":"image\/jpeg","w":990,"h":557}}`

Thank you all.

Comment: Could you please paste what is the result of `echo "twurl -H upload.twitter.com "/1.1/media/upload.json" -f ${image} -F media -X POST"`

Comment: Like this `{"media_id":1205943402870779904,"media_id_string":"1205943402870779904","size":56477,"expires_after_secs":86400,"image":{"image_type":"image\/jpeg","w":990,"h":557}}`

Comment: I mean the command that you copy and it works, not the output of working command.

Comment: `twurl -H upload.twitter.com "/1.1/media/upload.json" -f ~/Downloads/example.jpg -F media -X POST`

Comment: The problem is in the ${image}

Comment: Please edit your question so it contains working command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that `~` in `image` is interpreted as regular string instead of `$HOME` variable.

You probably setting your image variable like this:

```
image="~/Downloads/example.jpg"
```

That way `~` is not resolved.
You could remove quotes and set your variable this way:

```
image=~/Downloads/example.jpg
```

But the best approach will be to replace `~` with `${HOME}` or provide full path.

```
image="${HOME}/Downloads/example.jpg"
```